# Defining the output of a Wordpress Att

Tags: shortcode

I have this code where I'm trying to define how those attributes (ptid, ptle, pge ) will behave once the code runs. I would like to be able define them so to get them to execute functions before outputing the result.

```
    // Add Shortcode
function formatage( $atts , $content = null ) {

    // Attributes
    extract( shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'ptid' => '',
            'ptle' => '',
            ‘page’ => '',
        ), $atts )
    );

    // Code
return X
}
add_shortcode( 'p-fmt', 'formatage' );
```

p.s. anybody knows any good wiki about shortcodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure but do you want to get that attribute value to work on them ?

This is a way to do so

```
        // Add Shortcode
    function formatage( $atts , $content = null ) {

        // Attributes
        extract( shortcode_atts(
            array(
                'ptid' => '',
                'ptle' => '',
                ‘page’ => '',
            ), $atts )
        );

    $ptid = $atts['ptid'];
    $ptle = $atts['ptle'];
    $page = $atts['page'];

    if(!empty($ptid)){
   //include your php file here
   }else{ 
   //do something else 
   }
        // Code
    return X
    }
```

Comment: I want to write that if the attribute value has whatever in it to execute a php script and echo the result.

And if the value is empty to echo something else.

Comment: You can use `if(!empty($ptid)){//include your php file here}else{ //do something else }`

Comment: Can you edit your script above and show me where that would go?

Comment: Take a look now.I think you wanted this

Comment: Can I use the same concept with $Content ?

Comment: You can use the $Content value as well.See more on this [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode)